# Inheritance & Association

Tags: doctrine-orm

I need media entities defined like this:

Category:

- name       : string (25)
- slug       : string (25)
- description: text
- documents  : associaion with Document

Document = @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE"):

- category   : association (Category) and discriminator
- title      : string (50)
- description: text
- slug       : string (50)

For example, categories:
VIDEO:

- youtube
- dailymotion
- vimeo

PHOTO:

- locale photo
- cloud photo

FILE:

- locale file
- cloud file

A document of a category would be an instance of Document\Youtube etc ...

Is it possible to use a column as association field and discriminator for inheritance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) doesn't seem to mention a restriction about this.

However, as the column you want is a relation, the discriminator map would then rely on DB-issued IDs, which is not good in my opinion...

But you still can let Doctrine handle the discriminator for you: just declare a discriminator column you'll never use directly, declare its map, then rely on the entity logic to keep coherence between the category and the document type:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "youtube"="Youtube",
 *     "dailymotion"="Dailymotion",
 *     ...
 * })
*/
abstract class Document {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="documents")
    */
    protected $category;
    ...
    //this is to be called by children that all share a category field
    public function setCategory(Category $c) {
        $class = get_class($this);
        if (strtolower($c->getName()) !== strtolower(substr($class, strrpos($class, '\\') + 1))) {
            throw new \LogicException("Cannot bind " . $class . " to category " . $c->getName());
        }
        $this->category = $c;
        return $this;
    }
```